# How can I escape @ symbol in mail ID while using extra-index-url

Tags: python, escaping, special-characters

Here suppose, I'm using one mail id like `xyz.companyname@gmail.com` then when I'm trying to access this mail id for authentication, `@` symbol is getting converted to `%40`.

But here, I need `@` symbol to use my mail id as it is.

Comment: [urllib.parse.unquote](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [`urllib.parse.unquote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote) to *replace `%xx` escapes with their single-character equivalent*.

Try the following code:

```py
import urllib.parse
escapedEmail = 'xyz.companyname%40gmail.com'
print(urllib.parse.unquote(escapedEmail))
# Prints: 'xyz.companyname@gmail.com'
```